# Database design - model a 'Company' with 'Owner', 'Partner', 'Employee'

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on an app that has mainly two entities: `Company` and `User`. A `User` can be an `employee`, `owner`, or a `partner`.

My current approach of modelling this is:
[image]

Capacity is enum with possible values: employee, owner, partner

Someone got me confused suggesting I should have three separate tables for each of these capacities, which I don't think is right.

I'm terribly unsure whether the capacity could grow to more in future.

Should I create another capacity table and reference it in Personnel as a foreign key, in case we wish to add more capacity? Would that be a scalable (and right) approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Schema design is an [iterative process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative) (look at the links and links within) and providing advice on schema design is a bit beyond the scope of this forum. What you want to do is to implement a solution, play around with it, fix the bugs (and there **WILL** be bugs), change the schema - then rinse and repeat. I suggest that you do that and then come back to us if you have more specific questions. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: In your model a company can have more than 1 owner. Is this what you want? Also, a user can be an owner, employee or partner of multiple companies. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Colin'tHart yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not have separate tables but you might want to consider not using `enum` for the capacity column.

Instead use a table named, perhaps, `capacity` that has an id referenced in the `personnel` table (much like user ID and company ID). That makes it trivial to add new titles/positions without disturbing anything else.

Comment: And here's [why](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) you don't want to use `ENUM`s!

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I had in my mind. Thanks very much.